# Popular science books introducing therapeutic use of psychedelic drugs

Tags: psychiatry, psychology, drugs, psychedelics

I'm not a psychologist nor a psychiatrist, but I have the impression that research of therapeutic use of psychedelic drugs (MDMA, LSD, DMT, etc) is undergoing a revival and is very slowly being accepted by the medical establishment.

Are there introductory books covering this topic which are scientifically credible?

Comment: The word you want is probably "psychedelic" rather than "psychoactive" - psychoactive just means that it has some effect on the brain/mental activity. Caffeine is psychoactive, allergy medication is psychoactive, etc.

Comment: I removed the subjective 'good' part and emphasized the request for a 'popular science' (introductory level) book, which might make this question focused enough. I will leave it up to the community to decide on that.

Comment: P.s. in case you have _any_ sources you could link to clarify where this impression you have comes from, that would improve this question (would help attracting some up votes!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the psychedelic Renaissance/ third wave (as I've heard it being called) is steadily gaining momentum. I almost feel like mentioning How to Change Your Mind by Michael Pollan here is too obvious, but just to be safe, here's a [few](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=EC0210460EA2835A5535BAC36FAF93CB) [links](https://www.amazon.ca/Change-Your-Mind-Consciousness-Transcendence/dp/1594204225) and a cultural [review](https://www.brainpickings.org/2018/07/11/how-to-change-your-mind-michael-pollan/). There is also an exhaustive summary on [Trippingly.net](https://www.trippingly.net/lsd-studies/2018/5/15/how-to-change-your-mind)!

Answer (score 0):

Although there may be books written, your best bet for reading up on a changing field is to read some recent review articles.

Google Scholar is a good place to find such articles, for example you can search for "review psychedelic therapy" or substitute in a particular drug of interest. You can also select a recent year range if you want the newest sources.

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2014&q=review+psychedelic+therapy

Comment: The OP Is asking for an 'introductory' book, which I interpreted as 'popular science'. I imagine a review article does not fall under that category. :)

Comment: @StevenJeuris "Pop science" was your edit, not the OP, they just asked for a book, and they didn't talk much about their background. Review articles can be quite accessible, even to scientific novices, given they are interested in the topic. I see no reason to be afraid of scientific literature.

Comment: Fair enough. I just narrowed down the question, in line with what I perceived the OP was after, so it would not attract further down/close votes (list-like questions such as this are tricky). P.s. I did not down vote.